# How do we access the form elements of a child jsp file which is loaded in a modal window (using div) in the parent jsp file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, modal-dialog, simplemodal

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <div id="contentindiv"></div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the above div in my parent jsp file and I am using css to create a modal window effect of this div when a button is clicked.

I am loading a new jsp page in this div using

```
$("#contentindiv").html('<object data= <sample.jsp>');
window.location.href="#openModal";
```

My sample.jsp file has a text box with id tb1 and when the user enters in the modal window, I want to close the modal window and reflect it in a text box on the main jsp file whose id is tb2.

I tried accessing using document.getElementById(tb2) but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

I either have to access the child jsp element from the parent jsp or set the parent jsp element from the child jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
$('#openModal').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        var text = $('#tb1').val();
        $('.close').trigger('click');
        $('#tb2').val(text);
    }
});
```